Does the Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector generalize to higher dimensions?
The Kepler problem in three spatial dimensions has a non-obvious $\mathrm{SO}(4)$ symmetry that leads to the conservation of the Laplace-Runge-Lenz vector via Noether's theorem.
Does this only hold in three spatial dimensions? Or is does the natural generalization of the Kepler problem to higher dimensions - i.e. a central potential $V(r) \propto r^{-(d-2)}$ proportional to the Green's function for the Laplacian - also have some kind of non-obvious $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ symmetry? Is there any other way to generalize the LRL vector to higher dimensions? (I'm guessing that if so, in higher dimensions it would probably generalize to a higher-rank tensor rather than a vector.)

Related: https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2015/03/17/planets_in_the_4th_dimension/

@PM2Ring It looks like he only considers the generalization of the Kepler problem to higher dimensions where the attractive force stays proportional to $1/r^2$, regardless of the dimension. He shows that in that case, the LRL vector generalizes to a bivector (with cross products promoted to wedge products as usual).

But isn't that generalization of the Kepler problem to higher dimensions pretty trivial? Doesn't the orbit stay confined to the plane through the origin spanned by the initial position and initial velocity vectors, and the usual 2D calculation goes through verbatim? All but two of the dimensions seem totally irrelevant in that case. I think the more interesting generalization to higher dimensions would have the force fall off like $r^{-(d-1)}$, as I proposed in the OP.

Sure, it's only $1/r^2$, not what your question is asking about. But I think it's nice that the LRL problem is simplified by the "trick" of turning elliptical orbits into circular orbits by adding a space dimension (and using a different time parameter).

That's why I said it's related. I didn't say it solved your problem. OTOH, orbits in $1/r^{d-1}$ gravity are pretty boring in $d>3$: only circles work. Here's more from Greg Egan on LRL: https://www.gregegan.net/SCIENCE/LRL/LRL.html

@PM2Ring Aren’t circles the only closed orbits in higher $d$? Certainly you can have non-closed orbits that aren’t circles.

Yes, I meant closed orbits.
